# Can this be possible to array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to bash and I just to ask if below code (multiple if statements) can be converted into array?
Here:

```
if [ "$(egrep -l 'PRODUCT' $LINE)" ];then
        VALUE='PRODUCT'
        elif [ "$(egrep -il 'SERVICE' $LINE)" ];    then
                    VALUE='SERVICE'
        elif [ "$(egrep -il 'COMMERCE' $LINE)" ];   then
                    VALUE='COMMERCE'
        elif [ "$(egrep -il 'EDUCATION' $LINE)" ];  then
                    VALUE='EDUCATION'
        else
                    VALUE='OTHERS'
fi
```

Comment: Try using a loop. Use `VALUE='OTHERS'` before the loop and iterate over the possible values, using your (parameterized) `if` statement in the loop body

Comment: Didn't get you. `Converted into array` what? do you want `VALUE` will contain multiple values like `(PRODUCT, OTHER,...) or do you want to reduce the code by putting possible values in array?

Comment: where's the attempt to solve it with an array?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're looking for, you can do something like this:

```
VALUE_OPTIONS=(PRODUCT SERVICE COMMERCE EDUCATION)

VALUE='OTHERS'  # Default value, in case none of the "real" values match
for V in "${VALUE_OPTIONS[@]}"; do
    if egrep -iq "$V" "$LINE"; then
        VALUE="$V"
        break
    fi
done
```

This loops through all of the elements of VALUE_OPTIONS; if it finds a match, it sets VALUE to the matched element, then uses `break` to skip checking the other elements. If nothing matches, VALUE remains set to 'OTHERS' after the loop.

Note that I replaced `[ "$(egrep ... )" ]` with just `egrep -s` -- the `if` statement checks the exit status of the command, and `egrep` succeeds if it finds a match, fails otherwise. Since this means we don't need (or want) it to print the actual match, I added the `-q` ("quiet") option to suppress output, and removed the `-l` option because listing the file the match was found in is doubly irrelevant.

BTW, that `egrep` command looks wrong. Are you trying to search in LINE, or in a file whose name is stored in LINE? Because `egrep` expects to be given filenames, not the text to search in. If LINE has the text, you should use:

```
if echo "$LINE" | egrep -iq "$V"; then
```

In either case, you should almost certainly put `$LINE` in double-quotes (as I did above), to avoid unexpected interpretation (word splitting, wildcard expansion, ...) of its contents. In shell scripts, almost all variable references should be double-quoted.